# Как лучше организовать модуль по обработке ошибок?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Есть нубский вопрос, который я решил(как нуб), но хотелось бы улучшить то,что я сделал. Пишу на `ReactJS`, мне с `api` приходят данные, например объект clients. Если все в порядке, то приходит `clients:{clients:[], total: 10}`. Но если есть какая-то проблема на серверной части,или прозошло еще что-то внештатное может прийти объект с ошибкой, например `clients:`{error: "no data"}. Собственно и в одном и в другом случае объект попадает в props и достать его не проблема, но надо сделать проверку на ошибку и вывести текст ошибки в компоненте. СОбственно говоря, можно прямо в компоненте смотреть этот объект, проверять, если в нем есть поле `error`  и выводить текст ошибки, однако мне кажется этот вариант не очень хорошим, т.к. возможно, в будущем структура поменяется и мне придется в каждой компоненте все переделывать. Вместо этого я подумал,что неплохо написать отдельный модуль с методом-проверкой, который я могу в любой момент импортировать в любой компоненте. И если вдруг структура объекта изменится, то мне придется переделать только лишь модуль. Вот, что я сделал:

```
export function getErrorMessage(data){
    if (data.hasOwnProperty("error")) {
        return data.error;
    }

    return "";
}
```

соответственно в компоненте я его импортирую и использую:

```
import * as ErrorHandler       from "../../services/ErrorHandler"
```

...

```
 render() {
    let content;
    if (ErrorHandler.getErrorMessage(clients) !== "") {
                content = ErrorHandler.getErrorMessage(clients);
    }

    return (
    <div>{content}</div>
    )
    }
```

Мне видится это костыльным, поэтому я решл поинтересоваться у людей более опытных, как лучше было бы сделать такую штуку.

Comment: можете сделать HOC - компонент что то типа withError и в нём разрулить ваши ошибки...

Comment: HOC выглядит сложноватым решением. У вас redux или flux используется в проекте?

Comment: я ипользую redux